# Reusing cotton wool wicks during Hanukkah

Tags: halacha, chanuka, menora-chanukia

One who lights Hanukkah candles with oil and cotton wool wicks. Is it allowed to use yesterday's wicks again for the same candle or for another candle? There is no difference in the quality of light flame in the wicks that have already been used. Is it allowed to use the wick of the Shamash for a regular candle or the Shamash's wick for a regular candle? Should a new wick be put in the new candle of that day or can one of the old wicks also be used?

Comment: Is there a reason it wouldn't be allowed?

Comment: I would imagine it is just a question of hiddur, i.e. trying to do the mitzvah in the best possible way and therefore using fresh wicks each time

Comment: @Dov are fresh wicks better?

Comment: See OC 673:3-4 this shouldn't be an issue

Comment: @DoubleAA I was thinking out loud. Possibly using fresh wicks each time is more mehudar, the same way people make an effort to replace their aravos when they become more worse for wear

Comment: @Dov does wear make wicks worse? It's a metzius question

Comment: I hear. I am asking if from an appearance question it looks a bit shvach? Although I guess it could be argued if they're on fire you're not seeing "well presented" wicks

Answer (score 1):

You can learn from Shabbat candles where you singe the wicks to make them easier to light, [they are pre-charred therefore better (in משנה ברורה תרעג:לא it indicates even if they are pre-used)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.673.4?lang=he&with=Mishnah%20Berurah). Unless your taste prefers them to be new.
It's brought in Ben Ish Chai Halakhot you should pre singe the wicks so they're easy for the woman to light for the house.

Comment: This answer would be a great deal more compelling if it included citation of Halachic sources behind its assertion regarding Shabbat candles.

Comment: It's not obvious to me that a used wick, which is what the question is about, has the same status as a fresh, pre-singed wick, which is what the Shabbat candle citation refers to.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I would think the Hanukkah used one has a even higher status bc it's already kodesh which we don't say about Shabbat candles aren't they tashmishei kodesh?